# Perl/Regex to parse a string

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I am new to Perl and a little stumped on parsing the lines for a traceroute.  This is typical of the output that I am challenged with.

```
 3  someURL.net (184.106.126.128)  0.579 ms someURL.net (184.106.126.124)  0.742 ms  0.719 ms
```

Note how the 1st and 2nd routes use a different IP address. **This will change**; e.g., sometimes the hops will use all the same like this:

```
3  someURL.net (184.106.126.128)  0.579 ms  0.742 ms  0.719 ms
```

...**or**, each hop could have a different route, **or** they could all be the same.  I would like to use some regex, etc. in Perl to format the output like this:

```
3|url~ip~time|url~ip~time|url~ip~time
```

I'm not sure if I should loop through the individual words somehow, or if it is easier to do it all with regex. Any solutions or hints appreciated.

Comment: So the output from the example input would be this?
3|someURL.net~184.106.126.128~0.579 ms|someURL.net~184.106.126.124~0.742 ms|someURL.net~184.106.126.124~0.719 ms

Comment: @MetaEd Almost. I was not articulate about the time.  That is correct,  except there would be no " ms"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would it not be easier to use a traceroute module for perl? Is there any reason you need to parse raw traceroute output? (If just as an exercise for learning regex, sure.. but?)

[Net::Traceroute](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aTraceroute) would be what I'd use.

Comment: Thanks @mjbnz.  This is an interesting tool (I am new to Perl).  I installed it and am playing with it a little.  It is not immediately apparent to me if this tool can give output pertaining to each hop like ip and time_per_hop.

Comment: Take a look at the `hop_query_host()` and `hop_query_time()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

would this regex work

```
((\w+?\.\w+?)\ (\(\d+?\.\d+?\.\d+?\.\d+?\))(\ \d+?\.\d+?\ ms)+\ )+
     URL                  IP                    TIME
```